# How to disable only disconnect alerts in Treasure Tag?

Tags: 8.1, accessories, treasure-tag

I have a Nokia Treasure Tag (WS-2 model) hooked to my keychain and paired to my Lumia 920 (running 8.1 w/ Cyan). Overall it's working great. However, when I'm at home, my keys are usually in the front door and out of Bluetooth range of my phone (even though it's supposed to have a 40-metre range). This causes the Treasure Tag app to constantly trigger disconnect alerts and eat a lot of battery, as can be seen below:

[image]  [image]

In the Treasure Tag app, I've disabled the "Alerts on tag" option, but that only prevents the tag itself from beeping when the Bluetooth connection is lost. I've also had to disable audio and vibration alerts for the Treasure Tag app to keep it from driving me crazy, but this isn't ideal because a) the app still floods my notification centre, and b) I can no longer use the tag to find my phone. Same if I disconnect the tag altogether.

Is it possible to disable the disconnect alerts in the Treasure Tag app, without disabling other alerts (like when the button on the tag is pressed, or when the tag's battery is running low)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Treasure Tag app was recently (20 November 2014) updated to include a feature that neatly solves this problem, albeit in a different way than I imagined. Namely, you can now designate certain wireless networks as quiet zones, where alerts are automatically muted. This works great for me because I have wi-fi available both at home and at work, which are the two main places where my Treasure Tag is routinely out of Bluetooth range.

To set up quiet zones, do the following:

1. Open the Treasure Tag app
2. Expand the app bar (by tapping on "...") and select "quiet mode"
3. Tap on the wireless network you want to designate as a quiet zone (you have to connect to it first, of course), then tap OK to confirm

You can also tap the "+" icon at the bottom to add new wireless networks from the list of known networks without actually connecting to them.

To temporarily re-enable alerts for a wireless network, simply flick the toggle after it to the off position. Tap on any network to rename it, or remove it from the list of quiet zones.

[image] [image]

When you're connected to a wireless network designated as a quiet zone, the Treasure Tag app will let you know alerts have been muted, as will the tag's live tile, if you have it pinned to your Start screen.

[image] [image]